# updating column values when table name is a variable

Tags: r

First question here, and very new to R as well.

I have a loop creating data frames according to a list of studytables. I can read all the CSVs fine, but I would like to get the field "Subject" and add the variable "study" before what is currently in the field. My trouble is with the 2nd "assign" line, I can't get R to assign the new value to "Subject".

Thanks for all your help.

```
study <- 'study10'
studytables <- list('ae', 'subject')
studypath <- 'C:/mypath/'

for(table in studytables) {
  destinframe <- paste(table,study, sep='')
  file <- paste(studypath, table, '.CSV', sep='' )
  assign(destinframe, read.csv(file)) # create all dataframes 
  assign(destinframe['Subject'], rep('testing', nrow(get(destinframe))))
}
```

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to use `assign` like. If you're reading in a bunch of data.frames, it's better to keep them organized in a list rather than creating a bunch of different data.frame variables in your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `assign` like that really isn't a great idea. And as you can see it doesn't work well when you try to add columns to a data.frame. It's better to add the columns before you do the assign. So replace

```
assign(destinframe, read.csv(file))
assign(destinframe['Subject'], rep('testing', nrow(get(destinframe))))
```

with

```
dd <- read.csv(file)
dd$Subject <- paste(study, dd$Subject)
assign(destinframe, dd)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I don't think I was clear enough. I want to take what is currently in the Subject field and add what's in the variable "study" before it. So that's why I tried to get the data frame first to then update the Subject field.

Comment: Perfect, this worked exactly as I wanted. thank you !!